# When does a Spring @PostFilter execute?

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop

I am using spring's @Around annotations to provide caching of DAO calls and also using spring security's @PostFilter to restrict the viewing of certain records. However I am concerned that the cache could bypass the PostFilter and present a security problem.

How do I tell what order `@PostFilter` and `@Around` wrap the target object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an order of Spring Security's aspects by setting the `order` attribute of `<security:global-method-security>` (I guess it's zero by default).

You can also specify an order of your own aspect as described in [7.2.4.7 Advice ordering](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering):

> The highest precedence advice runs first "on the way in" (so given two pieces of before advice, the one with highest precedence runs first). "On the way out" from a join point, the highest precedence advice runs last (so given two pieces of after advice, the one with the highest precedence will run second).
>   ...
>   You can control the order of execution by specifying precedence. This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the org.springframework.core.Ordered interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the Order annotation. Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from Ordered.getValue() (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence.