# Issue with @PreAutorize annotation with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, pre-authentication

`@PreAuthorize` is not working in Spring Security 3.
 This is my code snap.

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin') or hasRole('Student')")
 public void doSomething(){}
```

It is giving me weird error (refer attachment)  [image]

Comment: Can you show the whole code of the class?

Comment: @geoand, I am not able to add whole code here, but I am sure that when I add only one line, server started to give me error. if I remove that line, Its working fine.

Comment: We need to know if the class or any of it's methods have been annotated when `@Transactional`, `@Scheduled` or some other Spring annotation

Comment: there is no methods annotated with `@Scheduled` in whole app but my service classes are annotated with `@Transactional`. but what is connection between @Transcational and @PreAuthorize ?

Comment: The issue is that in order to implement the functionality indicated by the annotations, Spring needs to create proxies. When multiple proxies are required, some things need to be configured correctly. Can you please show your Spring configuration?

Comment: is this link useful to me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856995/order-of-spring-transactional-and-spring-security-preauthorize

Comment: It could be, yes. Have you tried it? The most helpful thing would be for you to post the Spring config

Comment: Thanks @geoand, I fixed issue by adding `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"></aop:config>` line in spring-security.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for other interested people..

I fixed issue by adding

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"></aop:config>
```

line in spring-security.xml