# Security annotation @PreAuthorize doesn't take effect in @Controller, only in @Service with Spring Security 3.2.5

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

As the title implies.

Bellow is my spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter userPassAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(userPassAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

And my controller:

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public class RoleController {

    @Autowired
    private UserBusinessService userBusinessService

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/list_users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('N123ORMAL_ROLE1')")
    public Iterable listUsers() {
        return userBusinessService.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

Having this, when trying to access */api/list_users* with a user that doesn't have specified role, it can get it, without any problem. Even logs are perfect, without noticing anything. When move `@PreAuthorize` in `userBusinessService` at `getAllUsers()`, it work's as expected: error is thrown in logs and Access denied is returned.

Can anybody help me on get the `@PreAuthorize` annotation working for `@Controller` the same as for `@Service`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar issue with @Transactional and @PostFilter. The problem was an aop advice ordering problem.

This question helped me in that regard: [Order of Spring @Transactional and Spring Security @PreAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8856995/2248239)

I hope it helps to resolve your issue.