# What is wrong with my setup?

Tags: spring-security, spring-transactions, spring-test

Recently I workmate told me our test setup not working on windows with oracle jdk.

If I enable MethodSecurityConfig below exception occurring. If I disable MethodSecurityConfig it will work fine. But method security is necessary to me.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

How can I enable method security with @Transactional?

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class TestSecurityConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(value = 93)
public static class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

    @Autowired
    RoleVoter roleVoter;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        methodSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> voters = Arrays.asList(
                new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice),
                roleVoter,
                authenticatedVoter
        );

        return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@Order(94)
public static class MainSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter         {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    RoleVoter roleVoter;

    @Autowired
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Autowired
    SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> expressionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
                .expressionHandler(expressionHandler)
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter(){
        return new AuthenticatedVoter();
    }

    @Bean
    RoleVoter roleVoter(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
    }

    @Bean
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter, WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter, RoleVoter roleVoter) {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> voters = Arrays.asList(authenticatedVoter, webExpressionVoter, roleVoter);
        return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    }


    @Bean
    public WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter(SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler) {
        WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
        webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(webExpressionHandler);
        return webExpressionVoter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        methodSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
        return roleHierarchy;
    }
}
}
```

Test Case

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class TestBase {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .addFilters(new RequestContextFilter())
            .build();

}

@WithUserDetails(value = "hurelhuyag")
@Test
public void test1(){
    User user = userService.loadUserByUsername("hurelhuyag");
    Assert.assertNotNull(user);
    Assert.assertEquals("hurelhuyag", user.getLoginname());
}
}
```

[I full sample in github](https://github.com/hurelhuyag/testsample/)

Comment: Remove `@Transactional` from `UserService` interface and put above `SimpleUserService` implementation

Comment: Please try it and post the result. If it works, I can be sure, my thinking is correct and share with you.

Comment: @RamanujanR your wrong. `@Transacional` placed right place. Problem is  transaction proxy and method security proxy are conflicted. I don't know why.

Comment: Why did you declare `@Order` on `TestDataConfig`?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to configure the `order` attribute of the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation?

Comment: The same applies to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`: did you perhaps mean to configure the `order` attribute of that annotation?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856995/order-of-spring-transactional-and-spring-security-preauthorize

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436191/when-does-a-spring-postfilter-execute

Comment: @SamBrannen changing order is not helped.